# How do I stop MutationObserver from inserting my Chrome Extension multiple times on a SPA website?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, mutation-observers

For my Chrome Extension,
I'm searching multiple classes/id's to then include their text with some HTML I'm inserting into the website.

When I run the extension,
the HTML widget I'm inserting is inserted multiple times but should only be done once.

I realize MutationObserver is intended to check for every DOM change and seemingly inserts my widget every time that happens I presume. However, I'm not sure how best to approach making sure the widget is only inserted once.

I tried using `observer.disconnect();` which helps on initial load to insert the widget once but then it won't re-insert the widget on return to the page – will only on refresh. Couldn't figure out a way to turn observe back on.

Not sure if disconnect and reconnect is even a smart path but it's what I came up with.

In the attached screenshot, you can see it keeps adding the widget with DOM changes.

How should I approach fixing this?
Thank you!

[Link to download the extension](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/uq797hn6a74m9il/AABUNFhRO-RL-g39sK8Xtrmla?dl=0)

manifest.json

```
{
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "name": "Test SO Mutation Answer",
  "description": "Example for StackOverflow",
  "version": "0.0.1",

  "host_permissions": ["<all_urls>"],
  "permissions": ["storage", "activeTab", "scripting", "tabs", "webNavigation"],

  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["https://www.zillow.com/*"],
      "js": ["ballpark.js"],
      "css": ["main.css"]
    }
  ],

  "web_accessible_resources": [
    {
      "resources": ["/images/*"],
      "matches": ["<all_urls>"]
    }
  ]
}
```

ballpark.js

```
const observer = new MutationObserver(function() {
  if (document.getElementsByClassName('ds-action-bar')[0]) {
    if (document.querySelector('[data-testid="price"] span') && document.querySelector('.ds-expandable-card .eUxMDw')) {
      console.log("All data found");
      startWidget();

      if (document.getElementById('ballpark-container')) {
        console.log("Do nothing, BP exists");
      } else {
        console.log("Adding BP...");
        insertWidget();
      }
    } else {
      console.log("Cannot find all data");
    }

  } else {
    offerPrice = undefined;
    monthlyPITI = undefined;
  }
})

const target = document.querySelector('body');
const config = { childList: true };
observer.observe(target, config);


var offerPrice;
var monthlyPITI;

function startWidget() {
  getAskingPrice();
  getExpenses();
}

// Get Price from Zillow
function getAskingPrice() {
  var askingPrice = document.querySelector('[data-testid="price"] span');
  if(askingPrice !== null) {
    offerPrice = parseFloat(askingPrice.innerText.replace(/\$|,/g, ''));
    console.log(offerPrice + " Offer Price");
  } else {
    console.log("Null Asking Price Div");
  }
}

function getExpenses() {
  var monthlyPITIZillow = document.querySelector('.ds-expandable-card .eUxMDw');
  if (monthlyPITIZillow !== null) {
    monthlyPITI = parseFloat(monthlyPITIZillow.innerText.replace(/\$|,/g, ''));
    console.log(monthlyPITI + " PITI");
  } else {
    console.log("Null Monthly PITI Div");
  }
}

// Find Zillow widget to insert the extension widget
function insertWidget() {
  const select_div_for_bpd = document.querySelector('div.Spacer-c11n-8-65-2__sc-17suqs2-0');
  if(select_div_for_bpd !== null) {
    const ballpark_container = document.createElement("div");
    ballpark_container.setAttribute("id", "ballpark-container");
    select_div_for_bpd.appendChild(ballpark_container);

    ballpark_container.innerHTML = `
      <div class="ballpark-roi-container">
        <div><h1>${offerPrice}</h1> Offer Price</div>
        <div><h1>${monthlyPITI}</h1> Monthly PITI</div>
      </div>
    `;
  } else {
    console.log("Cannot insert your widget");
  }
}
```

[image: widget inserted multiple times but should be once]

Comment: I'm not sure if this is an efficient option, but checking for all the divs on the page first in the setup of the MutationObserver and then adding the widget. Something like, if X exists & Y exists & Z exists then startWidget. I'm gonna give this a shot but if there is a smarter way, I'm all ears.

Comment: Gave that a try but still running into the issue of multiple widgets being inserted.

Comment: Maybe not elegant but I figured it out. I just did another nested if statement. ONCE I know all the data exists then I do a check if my HTML widget already exists, if it does, don't insert widget, if it doesn't exist then insert the widget. Doesn't feel elegant but does the job.

Comment: Updated my code in the question that covers my fix. Nested if statements.